# Question about Abel theorem application

Tags: complex-analysis

About the application I found in my book that $\log 2=1 -\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}...$ and the explanation is

$\log 2 =\lim_{r\to 1^-} \log (1+r)$, this is straight forward

$\sum \frac {(-1)^{n-1}}{n}=\lim_{r\to 1^-} \sum \frac {(-1)^{n-1}}{n} r^n$, this is Abel theorem, so I also understand this part.

$\lim_{r\to 1^-} \log (1+r)=\lim_{r\to 1^-} \sum \frac {(-1)^{n-1}}{n} r^n$, how did they got this?

I really want to understand this to prepare for the final exam, so any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Maclaurin series for $\log(1 + r)$ is

$$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}r^n,$$

and this series representation is valid for $|r| < 1$. To get this series expression, consider the geometric series

$$\frac{1}{1 + r} = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty (-1)^n r^n, \quad |r| < 1.$$

Let $|x| < 1$. Integrating from $r = 0$ to $r = x$, we get

$$\log(1 + x) = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty (-1)^n \int_0^x r^n\, dr = \sum_{n =0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n+1}x^{n+1}.$$

By reindexing the last series, we obtain

$$\log(1 + x) = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}x^n.$$

Since this holds for all $|x| < 1$,

$$\lim_{x\to 1^{-}} \log(1 + x) = \lim_{x\to 1^{-}} \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}x^n.$$

Comment: You were too quick :) But that factorial in the last sentence???

Comment: I noticed and got rid of the factorials already. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: is there other explanation without using Maclaurin series, because I've learnt that in my complex variable class, but in analysis class I haven't learnt it yet, so I'm not sure If I can use that

Comment: I used the term "Maclaurin series" but it's the same as "Taylor series about zero". Have you not learnt Taylor series in class?

Comment: In this class, I don't recall learning about it. We only cover 5 chapter, which stop at residue. But I think Taylor series is basic knowledge enough to include without discussing about it. Beside, I don't think there is any other explanation than using Taylor series